# javascript internet explorer byte order mark

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, byte-order-mark

I am working on a way to save an HTML table to a csv file.  Ideally, this should be cross-browser, and I have gotten this to work on everything but Internet Explorer. However, I have gotten the obvious parts working.  What remains is that I am unable to get a working csv file from my JavaScript because a byte order mark is prepended to the data I wish to download.

I have confirmed that this is the case by downloading the csv file in IE and everything else and used a hex editor to view the raw file, I can confirm the file that Internet Explorer downloaded prepends the unicode character "FFFE".

Please see the code below this does this. saveTable takes an "<a>" node that is located inside a table.

If anyone can help me disgnose the issue and offer some solution I'd be grateful. Please forgive any faux pas on my part, I don't think I've ever used a site of this nature before. So if you need me to provide any further information please do just let me know and I shall do my best to get it on here.

```
function findTable(node) { // Finds a nodes parent table.
  return (node.nodeName !== "TABLE") ? findTable(node.parentNode) : node;
}

function saveTable(node) {
  var csv = [];
  var table = findTable(node);
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var header = [];
  var csv = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      // Do csv stuff.
      var dates = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("th");
      for (var j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) 
        (j == 0) ? header.push("") : header.push(dates[j].innerHTML);
      csv.push(header.join(","));
    }
    else {
      var rowArray = [];
      var jobName = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("th")[0].innerHTML;
      var times = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      rowArray.push(jobName);
      for (var k = 0; k < times.length; k++) 
        rowArray.push(times[k].innerHTML);
      csv.push(rowArray.join(","));
    }
  }

  node.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + csv.join("%0A"));
  var fileName = "spreadsheet_data-" + (new Date).getTime() + ".csv";

  if (node.download == "") 
    node.setAttribute("download", fileName);
  else {
    alert("Handle IE here!");
    var bom = "\uFFFE";
    var doc = document.open("application/octet-stream", "_blank");
    var data = csv.join("\r\n");
    doc.charset = "UTF-8";
    doc.write(data.replace(bom, ""));
    doc.focus();
    doc.execCommand('SaveAs', false, fileName);
    doc.close();
  }
}
```

Table example, it's not the way I would have chosen to do it myself, but it's how the table is generated by another piece of software.

```
<table id='results' border='1'>
<tr><th><a href='#' onClick='saveTable(this);' id='download_link'>Download data</a></th><th>2013/05/09</th><th>2013/05/10</th><th>2013/05/10</th><th>2013/05/10</th><th>2013/05/10</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>\PDF\EXOVIGN.PDF</th><td>8.853</td><td>9.050</td><td>8.807</td><td>8.827</td><td>8.835</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you add the bare minimum HTML to your question to give us something to work with please? We only need one row of data in the table, and it doesn't need any styling.

Comment: Using IE8 on WS2003 I had to change the extension from ".csv" to ".txt" to make it save it (I don't want to apply the hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929863 ). I didn't get the BOM at the start of the file with or without the `data.replace`. If the broadband for my home computer is working again this evening, I'll be able to test it on W7/IE10.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, however ideally the user wouldn't need to rename the file. Is there a way around that do you know?

Comment: Using IE10 on W7, I can't find anything that works - changing the charset still results in a BOM being written (or the HTML of the original page). FWIW, LibreOffice Calc has no problem opening the resulting csv file with an `FFFE` BOM.

Comment: I have had to abandon this in favour of a server side solution. How do I mark your comment as the 'best answer' and close this?

Comment: I don't think you can mark a comment like that, so I've added an answer which basically says it's easier to do it server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no absolute requirement to do this client-side, it might save you a lot of hassle to send the file from the server instead.